# Android Retrofit2: How to read and set EditText values when fragment is created?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, retrofit2

I'm trying to read meteorological values like temperature, pressure... and I have some EditText in the main fragment layout, that opens immediatly when the application is opened.

The point is that I wanna call using Retrofit2 my API developed with Slim PHP, to read these values and then set the EditText texts with this values.

These are the onCreate and onCreateView methods I have in the fragment class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.readSummaryData();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_patient_index, container, false);

    editTextTemperature = v.findViewById(R.id.teperaturaTxt_patientMain);
    editTextPressure = v.findViewById(R.id.pressureTxt_patientMain);
    editTextHumidity = v.findViewById(R.id.humidityTxt_patientMain);

    editTextTemperature.setText(((temperature != null)) ? String.valueOf(temperature) : "NaN") + " ºC");
    editTextPressure.setText(((pressure != null) ? String.valueOf(pressure) : "NaN") + " hPa");
    editTextHumidity.setText(((humidity != null) ? String.valueOf(humidity) : "NaN") + " %");
return v;
}
```

And this is the readSummaryData method:

```
private void readSummaryData(){
    Call<ReadSummaryDataResponse> readSummaryData = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getAPI().readSummaryData();
    readSummaryData.enqueue(new Callback<ReadSummaryDataResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ReadSummaryDataResponse> call, Response<ReadSummaryDataResponse> response) {
            try {
                ReadSummaryDataResponse summaryDataResponse = response.body();
                if(!summaryDataResponse.getError()){
                    temperature = Math.round(summaryDataResponse.getSummary().getTMP() * 100.0) / 100.0;
                    pressure = Math.round(summaryDataResponse.getSummary().getPRE() * 100.0) / 100.0;
                    humidity = Math.round(summaryDataResponse.getSummary().getHR() * 100.0) / 100.0;
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ReadSummaryDataResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

The summaryData response contains the summary class which has the temperature, pressure and humidity values.

So when I open this fragment when starting the application the values ​​of the EditText are all "NaN", but if I go to another fragment, and then come back to the main fragment the values aren't "NaN".

I think this may be because the EditText.setText(String) is done before the readSummaryData, and I don't know how to solve it.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update `Edittext` inside when your api get done. Try this

```
if(!summaryDataResponse.getError()){
                    temperature = Math.round(summaryDataResponse.getSummary().getTMP() * 100.0) / 100.0;
                    pressure = Math.round(summaryDataResponse.getSummary().getPRE() * 100.0) / 100.0;
                    humidity = Math.round(summaryDataResponse.getSummary().getHR() * 100.0) / 100.0;
                    if (!isRemoving()) {
editTextTemperature.setText(((temperature != null)) ? String.valueOf(temperature) : "NaN") + " ºC");
    editTextPressure.setText(((pressure != null) ? String.valueOf(pressure) : "NaN") + " hPa");
    editTextHumidity.setText(((humidity != null)
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Yes, now it's working, thanks. But what is the isRemoving()?

Comment: because when fragment remove or destroy your API still call.  It means API done after that so you have to check to ensure only update UI if need